# Why to use Gram-Schmidt process to orthonormalise a basis instead of cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just had one semester in analytic geometry and another in linear algebra. I learned about the Gram–Schmidt process but I am unsure why It is actually needed. In analytic geometry, I learned about the [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) and let's suppose I need to orthonormalize a basis in 3-dimensions, I'd think first about doing the following:

- Take two vectors in the basis $\{\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c} \}$, calculate $\overline{a}\times \overline{b}$ and then multiply it by $\cfrac{1}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}$.
- Now I have a new vector which is normalized and perpendicular to both $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$. Take one of those, say $\overline{a}$ and multiply it by $\cfrac{1}{|\overline{a}|}$. This makes our new vector for our new orthonormalized basis.
- Now we need a third vector which is perpendicular to both of these and that is easy, It's just: $\cfrac{\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}\times \cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}}{\left|\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}\times \cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\right|}$
- Our orthonormalized basis is: $\left[\cfrac{a}{|a|}, \cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}, \cfrac{\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}\times \cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}}{\left|\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}\times \cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\right|}\right]$.

Just using the property that $u\times v$ is perpendicular to both $u,v$. But now, in my linear algebra lectures, they taught us the Gram-Schmidt process. Why do I need this new process instead of just do what I did above? Perhaps they are the same thing, but until the present moment, I failed to notice their sameness.

Comment: What about four dimensional?

Comment: The cross product is only defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (although there are ways to generalize it, I don't know if this generalization gives orthonormal vectors). Graham Schmidt, on the other hand, is easy to implement in any inner product space, and the computations are much easier, in my opinion.

Comment: The point of Gram-Schmidt is not just to make an orthonormal basis, but to do so in such a way that the span of the first $k $ vectors is unchanged, for $k = 1,\ldots,n $.

Comment: @AlphaGo Yes. I guess I wasn't clear but I wanted to know the difference for 3-dimensional space: For this case, it seems that using Gram-Schmidt or the cross product doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mention that you are interested in the case of three vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$, with the usual Euclidean norm.  I think you are implicitly assuming that the three vectors span $\mathbf{R}^3$.  But then why bother orthonormalizing at all?  We already have a standard orthonormal basis for $\mathbf{R}^3$.

A more typical use of the Gram-Schmidt process is when you have $k$ vectors that span a proper subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$, and you want to find an orthonormal basis for that subspace.  In that situation, you don't have a standard basis, so you have to construct your own.  As pointed out in the comment of littleO and the answer of Victor Vela, Gram-Schmidt gives an orthonormal basis whose first $j$ vectors span the same subspace as the first $j$ vectors of the original set.

Assuming you really did want to produce an orthonormal basis from three vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$, your procedure is the same as Gram-Schmidt, up to a certain point in the process.  Write your basis as
$$
\left[\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}, \cfrac{\cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\times\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}}{\left|\cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\times\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}\right|}, \cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\right].
$$
I have swapped your second and third basis vectors, and have reordered the factors in one of your cross products (which only changes the result by a sign).  You can check that $(\overline{a}\times \overline{b})\times\overline{c}=(\overline{c}\cdot \overline{a})\overline{b}-(\overline{c}\cdot \overline{b})\overline{a}$.  We may therefore rewrite the second basis vector as follows:
$$
\cfrac{\cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\times\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}}{\left|\cfrac{\overline{a}\times \overline{b}}{|\overline{a}\times \overline{b}|}\times\cfrac{\overline{a}}{|\overline{a}|}\right|}=\cfrac{(\overline{a}\times \overline{b})\times\overline{a}}{\lvert(\overline{a}\times \overline{b})\times\overline{a}\rvert}=\cfrac{\lvert\overline{a}\rvert^2\overline{b}-(\overline{a}\cdot\overline{b})\overline{a}}{\left\lvert\lvert\overline{a}\rvert^2\overline{b}-(\overline{a}\cdot\overline{b})\overline{a}\right\rvert}=\cfrac{\overline{b}-\left(\cfrac{\overline{a}}{\lvert\overline{a}\rvert}\cdot\overline{b}\right)\cfrac{\overline{a}}{\lvert\overline{a}\rvert}}{\left\lvert\overline{b}-\left(\cfrac{\overline{a}}{\lvert\overline{a}\rvert}\cdot\overline{b}\right)\cfrac{\overline{a}}{\lvert\overline{a}\rvert}\right\rvert}.
$$
This is exactly what Gram-Schmidt gives.

Some things to note: the numerator might be the zero vector (if $\overline{b}$ is a scalar multiple of $\overline{a}$), in which case we should omit the denominator.  In this situation, we get a proper subspace of $\mathbf{R}^3$, rather than all of $\mathbf{R}^3$.  Similarly, if $\overline{c}$ lies in the span of $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$, then the third vector that Gram-Schmidt gives will end up being zero. If, on the other hand, $\overline{a}$, $\overline{b}$, and $\overline{c}$ span $\mathbf{R}^3$, the result of your procedure (as modified above) and Gram-Schmidt will be the same (except possibly for the sign of the third vector).  The process by which this third vector is obtained is different, however.  Your procedure doesn't even use $\overline{c}$, whereas Gram-Schmidt does.

Answer (score 2):

The Gram-Schmidt process is the demonstration of the following theorem:

**Theorem**: let {$\bar u_1, \bar u_2, ... , \bar u_n$} be a base for an euclidean space E, and $L_i$ = L({$\bar u_1, \bar u_2, ... , \bar u_i$})

$\forall$ *i* = 1, 2, ... , n. Then $\exists$ {$\bar v_1, \bar v_2, ... , \bar v_n$} ortonormalized base for E by < , > so that

$L_i =$ L({$\bar v_1, \bar v_2, ... , \bar v_i$})  $\forall$ *i* = 1, 2, ... , n

**Notes**:

- L({$\bar u_i$}) is the linear span of {$\bar u_1, \bar u_2, ... , \bar u_i$}.
- < , > is the usual scalar product

The Gram-Schmidt method does not create a random ortonormalized base for E; it is so that the vector subspaces L({$\bar u_1, \bar u_2, ... , \bar u_i$}) and L({$\bar v_1, \bar v_2, ... , \bar v_i$}) are **the same** $\forall$ *i* = 1, 2, ... , n

**Demonstration (the Gram Schmidt Method)**:

**n = 1**

$\bar v_1 = \lambda\bar u_1;\qquad<\bar v_1, \bar v_1>\,=\,1$

$<\bar v_1, \bar v_1>\,=\,<\lambda \bar u_1, \lambda \bar u_1>\,=\,\lambda^2<\bar u_1, \bar u_1>\qquad(note\,that\,<\bar u_1, \bar u_1>\gt 0)$

Making $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{<\bar u_1, \bar u_1>}};\qquad\bar v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{<\bar u_1, \bar u_1>}}\cdot\bar u_1$ is so that

- L({$\bar v_1$}) $=$ $L_1$
- $<\bar v_1, \bar v_1>\,=\,1$

**n = 2**

$\bar v'_2 = \bar u_2+\lambda_1\bar v_1;\qquad<\bar v'_2, \bar v_1>\,=\,0$

$0\,=\,<\bar v'_2, \bar v_1>\,=\,<\bar u_2+\lambda_1\bar u_1, \bar v_1>\,=\,<\bar u_2, \bar v_1>+\lambda_1<\bar v_1,\bar v_1>\,=\,<\bar u_2, \bar v_1>+\lambda_1$

Making $\lambda_1\,=\,-<\bar u_2, \bar v_1>$, the vector $\bar v'_2$ is orthogonal to $\bar v_1$

$\bar v_2\,=\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{<\bar v'_2, \bar v'_2>}}\cdot\bar v'_2\,;\qquad(\bar v'_2=\bar u_2-<\bar u_2,\bar v_1>\bar v_1)$ is so that

- L({$\bar v_2,\bar v_1$}) $=$ $L_2$
- $<\bar v_2,\bar v_2>$ $= 1$

Suppose defined $<\bar v_1, \bar v_2, ... , \bar v_i>$ for $i\lt n$ so that $\bar v_1, \bar v_2, ... , \bar v_i$ are orthogonal two to two and

- $<\bar v_j,\bar v_j>\,=\,1\quad\forall j\,=\,1,2,\,...\, ,i$
- $L_j\,=\,L({\bar v_1, \bar v_2, ... , \bar v_j})\quad\forall j\,=\,1,2,\,...\, ,i$

$\bar v_{i+1}\,=\,\bar u_{i+1}+\lambda_1\bar v_1+\lambda_2\bar v_2+\,...\,+\lambda_i\bar v_i$

$0\,=\,<\bar v'_{i+1},\bar v_1>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1}+\lambda_1\bar v_1+\lambda_2\bar v_2+\,...\,+\lambda_i\bar v_i\,,\bar v_1>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_1>+\lambda_1<\bar v_1,\bar v_1>+\lambda_2<\bar v_2,\bar v_1>+\,...\,\lambda_i<\bar v_i,\bar v_1>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_1>+\lambda_1\qquad(\bar v_2,\,...\,,\bar v_i\,are\,orthogonal\,to\,\bar v_1)$

$0\,=\,<\bar v'_{i+1},\bar v_2>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1}+\lambda_1\bar v_1+\lambda_2\bar v_2+\,...\,+\lambda_i\bar v_i\,,\bar v_2>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_2>+\lambda_1<\bar v_1,\bar v_2>+\lambda_2<\bar v_2,\bar v_2>+\,...\,\lambda_i<\bar v_i,\bar v_2>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_2>+\lambda_2\qquad(\bar v_1,\bar v_3\,...\,,\bar v_i\,are\,orthogonal\,to\,\bar v_2)$

$\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.$

$0\,=\,<\bar v'_{i+1},\bar v_i>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1}+\lambda_1\bar v_1+\lambda_2\bar v_2+\,...\,+\lambda_i\bar v_i\,,\bar v_i>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_i>+\lambda_1<\bar v_1,\bar v_i>+\lambda_2<\bar v_2,\bar v_i>+\,...\,\lambda_i<\bar v_i,\bar v_i>\,=\,<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_i>+\lambda_i\qquad(\bar v_1,\,...\,,\bar v_{i-1}\,are\,orthogonal\,to\,\bar v_i)$

Making $\lambda_j=-<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_i>\;\forall j=1,2,\,...\,i$, the vector $\bar v'_{i+1}$ is orthogonal to $\bar v_1,\,\bar v_2,\,...\,,\bar v_i$

$\bar v_{i+1}\,=\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{<\bar v'_{i+1}, \bar v'_{i+1}>}}\cdot\bar v'_{i+1}\,;\qquad(\bar v'_{i+1}=\bar u_{i+1}-<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_1>\bar v_1-<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_2>\bar v_2-\,...\,-<\bar u_{i+1},\bar v_i>\bar v_i)$

is so that

- L({$\bar v_1,\,\bar v_2,\,...\,\bar v_{i+1}$}) $=$ $L_{i+1}$
- $<\bar v_{i+1},\bar v_{i+1}>$ $= 1$

As you can see, the Gram Schmidt Method is extendible to all finite euclidean spaces, which of course includes $\Bbb R^3$

Even more, the method you described to obtain the ortonormalized base of $\Bbb R^3$ **does not** preserve the vector subespaces, but in the trivial cases of $L_1$ and $L_3$.

Comment: You actually didn't need to prove the Gram-Schmidt method, one can find the proof easily on the internet and on linear algebra books. Only the final part of your answer actually answers my question.

Comment: "Even more, the method you described to obtain the ortonormalized base of $\Bbb R^3$ **does not** preserve the vector subespaces, but in the trivial cases of $L_1$ and $L_3$." --- If you swap the OPs second and third basis vectors, then all three of $L_1$, $L_2$, and $L_3$ are preserved.  See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the notification, I didn't notice it in first place.